# Modificar tabla SQL con columna de identidad

Tags: sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertar_usuario]
@nombres varchar(50),
@Login varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@Icono image,
@Nombre_de_icono varchar(max),
@Correo varchar(max),
@Rol varchar(max)
as 
if (exists (select Login FROM Usuario2 where Login = @Login))
raiserror('Ya existe un usuario con ese login o con ese icono',16,1)

ELSE
insert into Usuario2 
values(@nombres, @Login,@Password, @Icono,
@Nombre_de_icono,@Correo,@Rol)
```

Asi es la tabla normalmente, pero despues necesité crear una variable con nombre Estado. por lo cual quedó así:

```
USE [BASEADACURSO]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[insertar_usuario]    Script Date: 30/09/2019 19:47:19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insertar_usuario]
@nombres varchar(50),
@Login varchar(50),
@Password varchar(50),
@Icono image,
@Nombre_de_icono varchar(max),
@Correo varchar(max),
@Rol varchar(max),
@Estado varchar(50)
as 
if (exists (select Login FROM Usuario2 where Login = @Login))
raiserror('Ya existe un usuario con ese login o con ese icono',16,1)

ELSE
insert into Usuario2 
values(@nombres, @Login,@Password, @Icono,
@Nombre_de_icono,@Correo,@Rol,@Estado)
```

Pero al intentar modificarla me marca el siguiente error: Sólo puede especificarse un valor explícito para la columna de identidad de la tabla 'Usuario2' cuando se usa una lista de columnas e IDENTITY_INSERT es ON.

Investigando en internet veo que es un problema con la columa con identity pero no entiendo que tiene que ver con la columna Estado recien creada y porque muestra el error al momento de intentar agregar la columna

Comment: Copia la definición de la tabla en tu pregunta para poder entender mejor el problema. Establecer el IDENTITY_INSERT en OFF como te han sugerido puede generarte un problema mucho mayor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede probar este solucion, basada en [la misma pregunta en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005437/an-explicit-value-for-the-identity-column-in-table-can-only-be-specified-when-a#12089779)

```sql
if (exists (select Login FROM Usuario2 where Login = @Login))
    raiserror('Ya existe un usuario con ese login o con ese icono',16,1)
ELSE

SET IDENTITY_INSERT insertar_usuario ON

-- escribe los nombres de columnas en insert into
insert into Usuario2 (Nombres, Login, Password, Icono, Nombre_de_icono, Correo, Rol, Estado)
values(@nombres, @Login,@Password, @Icono,
@Nombre_de_icono,@Correo,@Rol,@Estado)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT insertar_usuario OFF
```